# Echo multiple variables with delimiter and prevent new line (in code) being printed in the output

Tags: bash, echo, delimiter

I would like to print a number of variables in a tab-delimited manor, and for the sake of code cleanliness, I would like it write it like the below:

```
for f in files*
do
echo -e "
$var1\t
$var2\t
$var3\t
$var4\t
"
done
```

```
output:
file1_var1   file1_var2   file1_var3   file1_var4
file2_var1   file2_var2   file2_var3   file2_var4
```

I can get it to work like this, but it is not very tidy:

```
echo -e "$var1\t$var2\t$var3\t$var4\t"
```

I have tried using something like this to replace the new lines with tabs, but it seems a bit cumbersome. Also I need to add a new line at the end to prevent multiple files being printed on the same line, and it adds a new line between each output line as well.

```
for i in files*
do
echo -e "
$var1\t
$var2\t
$var3\t
$var4\t
| sed '$!{:a;N;s/\n/\t/;ta}' 
"
echo -e "\n"
done
```

```
output:
file1_var1   file1_var2   file1_var3   file1_var4

file2_var1   file2_var2   file2_var3   file2_var4
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically never use `echo -e`.  You can almost always make it more elegant with `printf`, or simply `cat`

If you don't mind getting one spurious tab,

```
printf "%s\t" "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4"
printf '\n'
```

With a here document, you can write a simple `sed` script to replace all internal newlines with tabs.

```
sed 'N;N;N;s/\n/\t/g' <<:
$var1
$var2
$var3
$var4
:
```

(This is probably not entirely portable, but it works on MacOS and Ubuntu, so it should work most places you care about.)

Perhaps also look into `pr`, which can arrange things in a matrix.

```
printf "%s\n" "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4" | pr -bt4
```

(Again, probably not entirely portable, but works e.g. on Linux. On MacOS I had to remove the `b` option.)

It's not clear where the variables should come from; perhaps write a function to wrap `printf` if you just want to print its arguments in groups of four:

```
fourcols () {
    while [ $# -gt 4 ]; do
        fourcols "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"
        shift 4  # not portable to sh
    done
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        printf "%s" "$1"
        shift
        if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
            printf "\t%s" "$@"
        done
        printf "\n"
    done
}
```

Then you can just call `fourcols *` if you want to print all files in four columns, for example.

Comment: why not just `fourcols() { printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$@"; }` ?

Comment: Because that generates more tabs than necessary. If that's not a problem, of course, that's quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a function that joins its arguments as a TSV record:

```sh
tsvrecord() { first=$1; shift && printf '%s' "$first" "${@/#/$'\t'}"; echo; }

tsvrecord "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4"
```

**remark:** no TSV escaping is done here, so if a filepath contains `\t` or `\n` (which is allowed on Unix) then the resulting TSV will be broken.